# How to change bootstrap datepicker date to jalali date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using bootstrap date picker, but unfortunately it doesn't support jalali calender. I searched on google for conversion of it, but I didn't find anything useful. So I need to change the datepicker and customize it like this image below.

[image]

Comment: use [bootstrap-jalali-datepicker](https://github.com/mousavian/bootstrap-jalali-datepicker) and edit that as you want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

download file zip persian-datepicker in [persian-datepicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/)
then added
in file zip, Sample code is available

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="../lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/persian-datepicker-0.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/persian-date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/persian-datepicker-0.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

then html code sample added

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
<label>Select Date</label>
<input id="observer" type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
<div id="inlineDatepicker" data-date="2016/12/13 12:20" class="col-xs-12">   </div> 
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input id="inlineDatepickerAlt" type="text" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

then script jquery added

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#observer").persianDatepicker({
        altField: '#observer',
        altFormat: "YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss",
        observer: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss',
        timePicker: {
            enabled: true
        },
    });


    //inline datepicker
    $("#observer").css( "z-index", "1000" );
    window.pd = $("#inlineDatepicker").persianDatepicker({
        timePicker: {
            enabled: true
        },
        altField: '#inlineDatepickerAlt',
        altFormat: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm",

        checkDate: function (unix) {
            var output = true;
            var d = new persianDate(unix);
            if (d.date() == 20) {
                output = false;
            }
            return output;
        },
        checkMonth: function (month) {
            var output = true;
            if (month == 1) {
                output = false;
            }
            return output;

        }, checkYear: function (year) {
            var output = true;
            if (year == 1396) {
                output = false;
            }
            return output;
        }

    }).data('datepicker');
    $("#inlineDatepicker").pDatepicker("setDate", [1391, 12, 1, 11, 14]);

}); 
</script>
```

If time did not want
it is jquery

```
$("#observer").persianDatepicker({
        altField: '#observer',
        altFormat: "YYYY MM DD",
        observer: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    });
```

Comment: and how about get Gregorian  or timestamp from that?

Comment: hi. thanks so much for datetimepicker. but how we can convert persian digits to ebglish digits. picked date not work in my project becuseof persian digits .

Answer (score 6):

see [persian date](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/example/)

source code [babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/)
support datepicker & datetimepicker & timepicker jalali

Comment: Only link is not an answer. Put some code here or expand your answer with more thorough explanation